# Create Contour Plot from Pandas Groupby Dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, group-by, contour

I have following Pandas Dataframe:

```
In [66]: hdf.size()
Out[66]:
a           b
0           0.0          21004
            0.1         119903
            0.2         186579
            0.3         417349
            0.4         202723
            0.5         100906
            0.6          56386
            0.7           6080
            0.8           3596
            0.9           2391
            1.0           1963
            1.1           1730
            1.2           1663
            1.3           1614
            1.4           1309
...
186         0.2         15
            0.3          9
            0.4         21
            0.5          4
187         0.2          3
            0.3         10
            0.4         22
            0.5         10
188         0.0         11
            0.1         19
            0.2         20
            0.3         13
            0.4          7
            0.5          5
            0.6          1
Length: 4572, dtype: int64
```

You see, a from 0...188 and b in every group from some value to some value. And as the designated Z-value, the count of the occurence of the pair a/b.

How to get a countour or heatmap plot out of the grouped dataframe?

I have this (asking for the ?):

```
numcols, numrows = 30, 30
xi = np.linspace(0, 200, numcols)
yi = np.linspace(0, 6, numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zi = griddata(?, ?, hdf.size().values, xi, yi)
```

How to get the x and y values out of the Groupby object and plot a contour?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks a lot! My fault was, that I did not realize, that I have to apply some function to the groupby dataframe, like `.size()`, to work with it...

```
hdf = aggdf.groupby(['a','b']).size()
hdf
```

gives me

```
a           b
1           -2.0          1
            -1.9          1
            -1.8          1
            -1.7          2
            -1.6          5
            -1.5         10
            -1.4          9
            -1.3         21
            -1.2         34
            -1.1         67
            -1.0         65
            -0.9         94
            -0.8        180
            -0.7        242
            -0.6        239
...
187          0.4        22
             0.5        10
188         -0.6         2
            -0.5         2
            -0.4         1
            -0.3         2
            -0.2         5
            -0.1        10
            -0.0        18
             0.1        19
             0.2        20
             0.3        13
             0.4         7
             0.5         5
             0.6         1
Length: 8844, dtype: int64
```

With that, and your help CT Zhu, I could then do

```
hdfreset = hdf.reset_index()
hdfreset.columns = ['a', 'b', 'occurrence']
hdfpivot=hdfreset.pivot('a', 'b')
```

and this finally gave me the correct values to

```
X=hdfpivot.columns.levels[1].values
Y=hdfpivot.index.values
Z=hdfpivot.values
Xi,Yi = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
plt.contourf(Yi, Xi, Z, alpha=0.7, cmap=plt.cm.jet);
```

which leads to this beautiful contourf:

[image]

Comment: Great solution, you can accept your own answer, FYI.

Comment: how can this example be extended for meshgrid over >2 dimensions?

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to SO.

It looks quite clear that for each of your 'a' level, the numbers of 'b' levels are not the same, thus I will suggest the following solution:

```
In [44]:

print df #an example, you can get your dataframe in to this by rest_index()
    a  b     value
0   0  1  0.336885
1   0  2  0.276750
2   0  3  0.796488
3   1  1  0.156050
4   1  2  0.401942
5   1  3  0.252651
6   2  1  0.861911
7   2  2  0.914803
8   2  3  0.869331
9   3  1  0.284757
10  3  2  0.488330

[11 rows x 3 columns]
In [45]:
#notice that you will have some 'NAN' values
df=df.pivot('a', 'b', 'value')
In [46]:

X=df.columns.values
Y=df.index.values
Z=df.values
x,y=np.meshgrid(X, Y)
plt.contourf(x, y, Z) #the NAN will be plotted as white spaces
Out[46]:
<matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet instance at 0x1081385a8>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! One can fill the not available values for _b_ with zeros (_Z_). I forgot this, but I think it makes it easier, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure you can use `fillna()` in `pandas` to do it. But I think it dependents on whether 0 is a possible value for your data (and actually mean something)

Comment: I don't get the Groupby Object to work for me.

`Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`