# Easy way to convert pandas dataframe to meshgrid for arbitrary dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, pandas, scipy

I found this Q&A for converting dataframe to meshgrid, but could not find anything similar that works for arbitrary number of dimensions.
Please recommend an easy approach and give example if possible?

[Create Contour Plot from Pandas Groupby Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032282)

---

EDIT

Right now I have the following incomplete approach:

```
d=dict()
for acol in df1.columns[:1]:
   d[acol]=sorted(list(set(df1[acol])))

intgrid=meshgrid(*d.values())
intgrid={akey:avalue for akey,avalue in zip(d.keys(),intgrid)}
```